# Search file: check input

Tags: php

I have a website where you can navigate around the campus at my school.
For example a can be called J2626/J2617 and so on. The user can also search for teacher and find his/her room.

The problem I have is that I want my code to check if the user have typed in a correct room that exists in the database, if not, the website should say that the room or person does not exists on this campus.

Because right now if I type in only "J" it will display all rooms that start with J, and thats not how I want my site to work. And If i press search button when nothing is typed in, the site displays all the rooms.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$fileName = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . "../../db/bth_nav.sqlite";

if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $argument = $_GET['page'];
    $argument = "%" . $argument . "%";

    $db = new PDO("sqlite:$fileName");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM bth_nav WHERE name LIKE 
    (:nameOwner) OR owner LIKE (:nameOwner);');
    $stmt->execute(array($argument));
    $res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if (empty($res)) {
        header("Location: " . "http://" . $_SERVER['index.php']);
    }
    ?>

    <div class = "formObjectSearch">

        <?php foreach ($res as $val) { ?>
                <div class = "infoTab">
                    <h2><?= $val['name']; ?></h2>
                    <p>Guidance: <?= $val['info']; ?></p>
                    <p>Whos sitting here?: <?= $val['owner']; ?>
                </div>
               <img class = "buildingImage" src = "img/<?=   
               $val['image']; ?>"
                <?php
           }
}
                ?>
            </div>
```

This is where I will check if I'm correct:

```
if (empty($res)) {
    header("Location: " . "http://" . $_SERVER['index.php']);
}
```

Right now I have a header that does not work and I have tried diffrent things in this if without success. I dont want it to redirect really, I want it to display "There is no such room or person at this campus". And without redirecting or displaying the whole content of the database.

Any suggestions? I might just have stupid code.

Thanks.

Comment: do you mean a case sensitive query?

Answer (score 0):

if you want a case sensitive search query you can use BINARY e.g.

`SELECT * FROM`table`WHERE BINARY`column`= 'value'`